# Apache Spark broadcast error: Error sending message as driverActor is null [message = UpdateBlockInfo(BlockManagerId

Tags: apache-spark

I'm using Apache Spark 1.1.0 and I'm currently having issue with broadcast method. So when I call broadcast function on a small dataset to a 5 nodes cluster, I experiencing the "Error sending message as driverActor is null" after broadcast the variables several times (apps running under jboss).

Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem had been resolved through stopping restart SparkContext in the app(running in wildfly) because the actor system doesn't shutdown properly in this spark version.